# Constrained solution to Fredholm equation with Lagrange multipliers

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, integral-equations

I am numerically solving a Fredholm equation of the second kind:
\begin{align}
f(x) &= g(x) + \int_0^\infty K(x,t)f(t)\,dt,
\end{align}
by using a Gaussian quadrature rule to convert it into a system of linear equations. For the particular kernel $K$ in this application, the solutions $f(t)$ are not unique, except at a particular point $x_0$ where all solutions pass through the same point. As it happens I only need $f(x_0)$, so the non-uniqueness for $x\neq x_0$ is in theory not a problem. In practice, the non-uniqueness presents itself numerically by different choices of quadrature leading to different solutions, and in some occasions the system becomes highly ill-conditioned, which is often associated with the solution having a large derivative through $x_0$.

In an effort to improve numerical stability, I would like to be able to pick the solution with the minimal derivative through $x_0$, and have started thinking about using Lagrange multipliers.

I can write the derivative at $x_0$ as
\begin{align}
f_x(x_0) &= \int_0^\infty \left[ K_x(x_0,t)f(t) + g_x(t)\delta(t-x_0)\right]\,dt
\end{align}
where the subscript $x$ indicates the derivative w.r.t $x$.
So I believe I want to minimise this subject to the constraints (for each $x$):
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \left [K(x,t)-\delta(t-x)\right]f(t)\,dt = -g(x).
\end{align}
I have derived the following Euler-Lagrange equation for the Lagrange multipliers $\lambda(x)$:
\begin{align}
\left[K(x,t)-\delta(t-x)\right]\lambda(x) &= -K_x(x_0,t) \\
\lambda(x) &= -\frac{K_x(x_0,t)}{K(x,t)-\delta(t-x)},
\end{align}
but then I am really not sure where to go next.

Edit: substituting into the equation for $f_x(x_0)$, I get:
\begin{align}
f_x(x_0) &= g_x(x_0) - \lambda(x)\int_0^\infty\left[K(x,t)-\delta(t-x)\right]f(t)\,dt \\
&= g_x(x_0) - \lambda(x)g(x),
\end{align}
and then if I assume a solution can be found with $f_x(x_0)=0$, I have
$$\lambda(x) = g_x(x_0)/g(x).$$
Then substituting this back into the Euler-Lagrange equation, I get
\begin{align}
\left[K(x,t)-\delta(t-x)\right] &= -K_x(x_0,t)\frac{g(x)}{g_x(x_0)} ,
\end{align}
and then substituting back into the original equation:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \left [K(x,t)-\delta(t-x)\right]f(t)\,dt &= -g(x) \\
\int_0^\infty K_x(x_0,t)\frac{g(x)}{g_x(x_0)}f(t)\,dt &= g(x).
\end{align}
This would appear to give an equation I can solve for $f(t)$ with the constraint $f_x(x_0)=0$ built in. I'm sure there is some fatal flaw in my reasoning though.